# Reference a Rails route which only accepts post requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I finally realized that my custom route does not have a URL helper because it only accepts POST requests.

```
post :my_custom_callback, as: :my_custom_callback
```

I expected to be able to reference it in my code as `my_custom_callback_url` but it seems the helpers methods are only generated for GET requests. How can I configure my app to generate a named helper method for this route?

Answer (score 0):

I take it back. I forgot that routes are not available from the Rails console. This is how I had to access it:

```
Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.my_custom_callback
```

Thanks to @mori for pointing out that the Rails console provides quick access using:

```
app.my_custom_callback_url
```

Comment: Or from the console: `app.my_custom_callback_url`